# R unique command and table command disagree

Tags: r, floating-point, unique

I have a strange problem. To illustrate:

```
a <- c(3.099331946117620972814,
       3.099331946117621860992)

> unique(a)
[1] 3.099331946117620972814 3.099331946117621860992
> table(a)
a
3.09933194611762 
               2
```

So `unique()` correctly recognises that the numbers are different after the 15th digit. `table()` however does not consider them different.

This may be expected behaviour but it is causing an error in some of my code as I need them both to agree:

```
times <- sort(unique(times))
k <- as.numeric(table(times))
```

times is correctly pulling out unique times. k is supposed to be the count of number of times each time occurs, but because of the above issue it doesn't do this correctly.

Anyone have a suggestion to get unique and table to agree? (or other workaround?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to use `unique` or `table` on floating-point number is conceptually problematic from the computer's standpoint. This topic is strongly related to the [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), with an excerpt:

> The only numbers that can be represented exactly in R’s numeric type are integers and fractions whose denominator is a power of 2. All other numbers are internally rounded to (typically) 53 binary digits accuracy. As a result, two floating point numbers will not reliably be equal unless they have been computed by the same algorithm, and not always even then. For example,
>
> ```r
> R> a <- sqrt(2)
> R> a * a == 2
> [1] FALSE
> R> a * a - 2
> [1] 4.440892e-16
> R> print(a * a, digits = 18)
> [1] 2.00000000000000044
> ```

(Other examples exist, if curious I encourage you to read more in that FAQ topic.)

Because of this, I suggest you decide on a required precision, then use exactly those digits when looking for uniqueness. Using your numbers, you can force the issue with `format` (and `sprintf`):

```r
a <- c(3.099331946117620972814,
       3.099331946117621860992)

table(format(a, digits = 15))
# 3.09933194611762 
#                2 
table(format(a, digits = 16))
# 3.099331946117621 3.099331946117622 
#                 1                 1 

unique(format(a, digits = 15))
# [1] "3.09933194611762"
unique(format(a, digits = 16))
# [1] "3.099331946117621" "3.099331946117622"
```

---

For the curious, the reason `unique` and `table` are different is rooted somewhere in `table`'s use of `factor`, which in turn uses `as.character(y)`. If you do `as.character(a)`, it is arbitrarily cutting the precision to 14 digits:

```r
as.character(a)
# [1] "3.09933194611762" "3.09933194611762"
```

So to answer the question you *asked*: `unique` and `table` are different because `table` ultimately uses `as.character`, which by default truncates to 14 digits here. (Since it's a primitive, you'll have to go into the low-level source to figure that one out.)

The question I answered above is to the underlying assumption that using `unique` on floating-point is a good thing to do (which I argue "it is not").

Comment: Great answer thanks. Hmm, now my dilemma is what is a sensible precision given I want this fairly general? But I'll  figure something out on that I guess 

Comment: Actually. This turns out to be useful. I added a variable to control the digits that in effect now allows the user to decide what difference in times is meaningful, which I think will have a few advantages. thanks again for great answer!

Comment: User-controlled configurability is almost always (imo) an enhancer, providing transparency and flexibility. I really enjoy "aha" moments like that! (And not everybody will agree on a level of precision that *you* think is relevant, so this could be perceived as less-selfish from the users' perspective :-)

Comment: This answer does not explain why `table` considers the numbers to be the same. The numbers are different as stored by R, as shown by the fact that `unique` recognizes them as different. So the documentation about how they are represented in R does not make them indistinguishable. And the text about results possibly varying due to method of computation is irrelevant as we have static results in `a`—the same data is passed to `unique` as is passed to `table`. Possibly `table` is doing some massaging its data, such as rounding it to lower precision. In such case, an answer should explain it.

Comment: The suggestion to “decide on a required precision, then use exactly those digits when looking for uniqueness” is faulty. Any rounding method creates a number of intervals in which every number in an interval is rounded to the same value. For any two numbers lying in one interval, this will identify them as equal (sometimes falsely). However, for any two numbers straddling the endpoint of an interval, it will not identify them as equal. Since the distance between any two numbers straddling a point may be arbitrarily small (in real arithmetic) or a single ULP (in floating-point), this technique…

Comment: … fails to treat numbers that are very close together as equal for some pairs of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I argue that your "faulty" judgement is missing the point of the FAQ 7.31: expecting any two numbers to be precisely equal when dealing with floating-point number is problematic from the start. The recommended way to determine if two floating point numbers are equal is to determine a level of precision above which there is no function difference. That's just a fact with [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (and perhaps others), handling floating point numbers with a limited number of bits in the mantissa.

Comment: I understand that you feel the underlying cause should be in the answer, but even if I can find the underlying cause in `table`, the premise of using `unique` with floating-point numbers is flawed from the start. So while it would be ideal to perfectly answer what is asked, answers often need to address the underlying problem, regardless of what the OP actually asked. This is (in my view) such a case.

Comment: The underlying problem seems to be due to `table`'s use of `factor`, which uses `as.character` on the numbers, which truncates to 14 digits.

Comment: It is **not** “just a fact” that “The recommended way to determine if two floating point numbers are equal is to determine a level of precision above which there is no function difference.” What person qualified in floating-point arithmetic recommends that, and what is their justification? The [FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) you refer to mentions that `all.equal()` compares with a tolerance, but it does not actually recommend it, nor does it give any reason, nor does the Heiberger and Holland discussion it mentions.

Comment: Generally, recommendations for comparing with a tolerance are folklore, often come from amateurs, and often fail to discuss the problems this causes. Comparing with a tolerance reduces false negatives (false reports that two numbers computed with floating-point arithmetic differ even though the numbers would have been equal had they been computed with real-number arithmetic) at the expense of increasing false positives (false reports that two numbers are equal although they are actually different if computed with real arithmetic). You cannot properly recommend a solution that…

Comment: … may introduce bugs without knowing anything about the application. About the only proper use for comparing with a tolerance I have seen is for testing purposes—for attempting to test whether some algorithm implementation contains bugs. If an algorithm is buggy, there is likely some situation in which its output is very different from the ideal output, but there may be many situations in which the output is very close to the ideal output. In that situation, comparing with a tolerance will find many bugs, pass many working programs, and miss few programs with bugs. So that is a good use.…

Comment: … Outside of that, when people are having problems comparing floating-point numbers for equality, a better recommendation for comparing with a tolerance, for which there is no general solution, is to reconsider whether you should be comparing floating-point numbers at all. Attempting to do so is often a sign of misuse of floating-point arithmetic or a poor design or goal. So that is what the recommendation ought to be: Not to compare with a tolerance, but to reconsider the design. And we certainly should not be recommending people introduce new bugs into their comparisons without warning.

Comment: On top of that, comparing numbers by reducing their precision then comparing is different from comparing by using a tolerance. The former fails to accept some close numbers as possibly equal, while the latter breaks the transitive property (and both create false positives).

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree with: *"sign of misuse of floating-point arithmetic or a poor design or goal"*, and perhaps out of everything, that will be my take-away from this beat-down. For you, I'll soften my tone on floating-point kludgery in R, since I certainly have something to learn from somebody who's served on the IEEE-754 revision committee (no sarcasm). For your part, how about contributing something to the R community and help make the R FAQ (at least 7.31) more informative and helpful (and accurate)? There's nothing saying the FAQ cannot consider the pedagogy of its assertions.

Comment: I also suggest you provide an answer as well to this question that adequately reflects what I've missed. Again, no sarcasm, I really would like to find another way to educate and communicate on this topic.

Comment: One more thing: *thank you* for replying when I asked about the down-vote ... that's the first request that's been answered (in a long time if ever), and even *I* can learn something new. Thanks.