# Subset the multiple columns by its values in R

Tags: r

My data is quite large, so I create a small matrix to better illustrate my demand.

```
test <- matrix(c(1:3, rep(0.5,3),4:1), nrow = 1, dimnames = list(1, 1:10))
```

The matrix will like this:

```
   1   2   3    4    5    6   7   8   9   10
1  1   2   3   0.5  0.5  0.5  4   3   2    1
```

I want to subset this matrix with multiple columns when its value is equal to specifc value likes 0.5:

```
     4    5    6   
1   0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Since my data would have more than 10,000 columns, I'm looking for codes that can solve my problem.

Comment: You may need `test[,test == 0.5, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: In general, tests of *equality* with floating-point numbers is flawed. While it may work in some circumstances, you cannot rely on it working all of the time (see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)). You are much better off using tests of *inequality* and/or using context-specific tolerance (e.g., `abs(test - 0.5) < 1e-9`).

Comment: Notably, while I am not an expert in IEEE-754 (floating-point stored digitally), in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56609352/3358272) of mine, a user allegedly very involved in the IEEE-754 educated/schooled me a bit. While some of the back/forth commentary is a little adversarial, I think many of Eric's points are very salient, and something good to consider. R lets you be sloppy, and I know I've been burned several times assuming floating-point equality would work well-enough.